# Understanding the "Width Specifier" on the PHP sprintf function

Tags: php, printf

I'm just starting out teaching myself to code using PHP. The tutorial I'm using threw this at me:

`echo "Circumference of a circle with radius $x is ".sprintf("%4.2f",(2 * $x * pi()))."<br />";`

I've been able to figure out what most of this is, except for the number 4. According to the PHP Manual, a number after the % sign in a sprintf function is:

`a width specifier that says how many characters (minimum) this conversion should result in.`

However, if $x = 1, the output is "6.28" which obviously isn't 4 digits. No matter what number I change the 4 to, the output remains unchanged. Even if I remove the 4 completely, so that it reads "%.2f", the output still remains unchanged. The only thing that seems to have any impact is if I change the 4 to a massively large number, like 1000000000. Then, I get an error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1006632960 bytes)`

So what exactly is that 4 meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exactly what it says it does, as you can see if you look at the page source. The HTML layout engine is folding all the spaces into a single whitespace token which is why you will never see it if you look at the processed output.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the decimal place is being counted as a character, and it creates blank spaces to fill out any additional characters needed.

Thank you!